# on_member_join not giving roles when a member joins the server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that will do certain things when a member joins the server. More precisely, it has to give them some roles and DM the member.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    roles = {"Level": 705112591927869513, "Interests": 705116168444444773, "Region": 725984087948656710,
             "Subscriptions": 705122149152850062}
    
    member_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name = "member")
    await member.add_roles(member_role)
    for role in roles.keys():
        newrole = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = roles[role])
        await member.add_roles(newrole)
    await member.send("Welcome to the server! Please read the rules and verify yourself to be able to type! "
"Link to jump directly to the message - link")
```

My issue is that, for reason, it doesn't work consistently. Sometimes it gives all the roles, others just the member one and others none at all. I understand that not all members will get the DM (because of the privacy settings) and that's fine, but I don't really get why not all members get all the roles when they join. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This maybe because of the rate limits of Discord API.

This may work

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    roles = {"Level": 705112591927869513, "Interests": 705116168444444773, "Region": 725984087948656710,
             "Subscriptions": 705122149152850062}
    
    member_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name = "member")
    await member.add_roles(member_role)
    roles = [member.guild.get_role(i) for i in roles.values()]
    await member.add_roles(*roles)
    await member.send("Welcome to the server! Please read the rules and verify yourself to be able to type! "
"Link to jump directly to the message - link")
```